# $lookup returns [] 0 elements array

Tags: mongodb, join, nosql, aggregation-framework, lookup

I am doing a project in MongoDB and am a beginner trying to learn and apply the knowledge.

My first collection is Movies (is like this):

```
{
    "Movie_ID": {
        "$numberInt": "31"
    },
    "Movie_Name": "Tanhajhi",
    "Release_Date": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1578643200000"
        }
    },
    "Genre": "Action"
}
```

My second collection Rating (is like this):

```
{
    "Rating_ID": {
        "$numberInt": "61"
    },
    "Person_ID": {
        "$numberInt": "11"
    },
    "Movie_ID": {
        "$numberInt": "31"
    },
    "Theatre_ID": {
        "$numberInt": "21"
    },
    "Movie_Rating": {
        "$numberInt": "5"
    },
    "Theatre_Rating": {
        "$numberInt": "2"
    }
}
```

I am trying to find which movie has got what review by which people. So I wrote a code like this:

```
db.Movies.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $lookup:   
                {
                    from: "Ratings",
                    localField: "Movie_ID",
                    foreignField: "Movie_ID",
                    as: "M_Ratings"
                }
        }
    ]
)
```

But the above code returns an empty array (0 elements in it).

Comment: It [works](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gryhnF38FHF) as expected

Answer (score 0):

your `$lookup` is great,
the problem is with the definition of the int fields -> `"$numberInt": "61"`

if you want the field to be numeric the 2 best options are:

```js
"Movie_ID": 31, // Your number will be double 
"Movie_ID": NumberInt("31"), // Your number will be int32
```

Either way, the `$lookup` should work perfectly after this fix (for all int fields you defined)

take it from here,

```js
use your.own_db

db.Movies.insertOne(
   {
    "Movie_ID": NumberInt("31"),
    ,
    "Movie_Name": "Tanhajhi",
    "Release_Date": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1578643200000"
        }
    },
    "Genre": "Action"
}
)

db.Ratings.insertOne(
   {
    "Rating_ID": {
        $numberInt: "61"
    },
    "Person_ID": {
        "$numberInt": "11"
    },
    "Movie_ID": {
        "$numberInt": "31"
    },
    "Theatre_ID": {
        "$numberInt": "21"
    },
    "Movie_Rating": {
        "$numberInt": "5"
    },
    "Theatre_Rating": {
        "$numberInt": "2"
    }
}
)

db.Movies.find()
db.Ratings.find()
```

```
enter code here
```